# executing javascript in PHP through echo, via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

so i build a login user system that has int eh html page a div container and a javascript file. in the javascript file, it makes ajax calls to different php pages that then echo back the html code for the form selected that is then inserted into the div container.

(Thus the page does not refresh - its dynamic content. and if someone grabs the source, all they get is the js file and a div container)

my problem nw is i need to run some javascript in the echo'd html in the php that is being called via ajax.

so ajax call to php, php echos a string and the ajax then performs a document.getElementById("Container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

The php code i have has a 2 input fields, and i need it to element .focus ont he first one. so i have something like this being echod'd:

```
echo "

<form>
<input name='username' type='text' id='username'>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('username').focus();
</script>

";
```

And guess what, it does not work..
Please help

Comment: Guess what, the code you posted works on my computer.

Comment: You mean you want to execute `document.getElementById('username').focus()` after it is returned as an ajax response.

Comment: it work well http://jsfiddle.net/Awea/q3WJk/

Comment: Ace is correct, stop running the php code, that works, when i pump it through an ajax post and document.getElementById('div_container').responcetext.. it does not, why

Comment: It does not work because you are not telling it to be executed. Browser does not know you've added that code to the source. I've edited my answer and added some ideas. Best one is using a js framework. Easiest and dirtiest would be using eval().

Answer (score 1):

*(Thus the page does not refresh - its dynamic content. and if someone grabs the source, all they get is the js file and a div container)*

They can still easily get the full source, by using firebug (firefox add-on) or some other tool. You can't protect your source code this way.

**Idea #1:**
Use DOM to get the AJAX response, then append the new javascript to the head of the document.

**Idea #2:**
Use a js framework to get the response, much easier. I know jQuery executes the script in AJAX response (getScript function, [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript)). Here is a question with answers to do the same with [Prototype framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278122/how-to-force-javascript-to-execute-within-html-response-to-ajax-request).

**Idea #3:**
Use eval(). This is not considered good practice though:

```
eval(document.getElementById('username').focus());
```

Answer (score 0):

php is not problem here, nor in html nor in script. It works

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/a571a.php

Comment: I think the code he just echo'd is from an ajax response and he wants to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, it's very powerfull and easy js-library. You can do it in the success callback function like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'your_request_url_here',
    dataType: 'html',
    success:function(html){
        $("#Container").html(html);
        $("#username").focus();
    }
});

It will be better if you will call the ajax request in the $(document).ready()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take the script out of the response and put it in your receiver code?

```
document.getElementById("Container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById('username').focus();
```

Comment: cos i use the function that fills that container in more then one case where 'username' does not exist