# PHP/HTML/JavaScript: <script> not working when called asynchronously using echo

Tags: javascript, php

The innerHTML attribute of a div on my webpage is updated asynchronously (XMLHttpRequest) by getting PHP from the server: but it doesn't seem to call javascript.

This works absolutely fine:

```
<div id="mydiv"><script>alert('hello');</script></div>
```

And this works absolutely fine (updating inner HTML of that same div):

```
echo "<p>Hello</p>";
```

But this does not work:

```
echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>";
```

And I have no idea why! I have tried this in multiple documents, and my searching online seems to suggest it should work.

This is only a problem that occurs when the content is asynchronous. The following works perfectly:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "<script>alert('hello');</script>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can easily design around this, but is it impossible to execute javascript code in this way? As far as I can see, this page suggests work-arounds but doesn't say explicitly that it's impossible: [executing javascript in PHP through echo, via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955965/executing-javascript-in-php-through-echo-via-ajax).

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: You can try Jquery $.post or $.get for this work

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding to your comments sooner! I simply wanted to know why it wasn't working - I couldn't understand why it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is echoing the `script` tags into the body of the html, but nothing is asking them the javascript to run. Either way, this is the wrong way to go about this.

You should just execute whatever javascript you want from the success function of your ajax request.

Usually I would pass a `JSON` object back from my `PHP` to the `success` handler, which would `JSON.parse` it and then do what you wanted with the return data, but you could also use `Javascripts` `eval()` although, this is discouraged in most cases due to security reasons.

Not using `eval()`;

Javascript;

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "path/to/php.php",  
    type:'POST',  
    data: {
        data: 'someString'
    },
    success: function(json){  
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        if(obj) {
            // run some javascript
        }
    },
});
```

PHP file (path/to/php.php);

```
<?php
    // create return object to pass back to client javascript
    $return = new stdClass();

    // if you have incoming data from the ajax request to the server
    $dataFromAjaxRequest = $_POST['data'];

    // do somehting with this data;
    if($dataFromAjaxRequest == "someString") {
        $return->success = true;
    } else {
        $return->success = false;
    }

    // clean the buffer
    ob_clean();

    // encode your return obj to JSON and echo it and die
    die(json_encode($return));
?>
```

Using `eval` to execute pure php generated Javascript;

Javascript;

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "path/to/php.php",  
    type:'POST',  
    data: {
        data: 'someString'
    },
    success: function(javascript){  
        eval(javascript);
    },
});
```

PHP file (path/to/php.php);

```
<?php
    // if you have incoming data from the ajax request to the server
    $dataFromAjaxRequest = $_POST['data'];

    // do somehting with this data;
    if($dataFromAjaxRequest == "someString") {
        $return = "alert('success!');";
    } else {
        $return = "alert('failure!');";
    }

    // clean the buffer
    ob_clean();

    // encode your return obj to JSON and echo it and die
    die($return);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was really the answer to my question: "What you are doing is echoing the script tags into the body of the html, but nothing is asking them the javascript to run."

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
  <html>
   <body>
       <script>eval(<?php echo 'alert('hello')';?>);
       </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For better cross-browser compatibility and less verbosity  I'd suggest jQuery.

```
$.get('http://example.com', function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```