# javascript from ajax won't run

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert

I have a page being ajaxed in, but the document ready code will not run. I'm running in IE7. I get no alert, but "Page is here" shows fine. The method "ajax" is a utility method I wrote. It works fine for all my ajax calls, so I know that's not the issue. I just can't get my javascript to run. Why would my javascript not be running?

AJAX Page

```
<script src="Utilities/Javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("RUN PLEASE");
</script>
Page is here
```

Main Page

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="Utilities/Javascript/Utilities.js"></script>
<script src="Utilities/Javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ajax("scrolltest.aspx", "divy2");
    });
</script>
<div id="divy2">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax method from Utilities.js

```
/*
* Ajax page loads with url and updates element's innerHtml
* @param url : URL to call for ajax page load
* @param element : Element ID to be updated
*/
function ajax(url, element) {
    var ajx;
    if (window.HXMLHttpRequest) {
        ajx = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        ajx = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    ajx.open("GET", url, true);
    ajx.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    ajx.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = ajx.responseText;
        }
        else if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 400) {
            alert("Page Error. Please refresh and try again.");
        }
        else if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 500) {
            alert("Server Error. Please refresh and try again.");
        }
        else if (ajx.readyState == 4) {
            alert(ajx.status + ":" + ajx.statusText);
        }
    }
    ajx.send();
}
```

Comment: Show us your Utilities.js file

Comment: @Aelios the only used method from that file has been added

Comment: You're using jQuery, why do you use a custom `ajax` method.  Use jQuery's `$.ajax` :-P

Comment: @Rocket or in this case, `$("whatever").load( ... ); `

Comment: @rocket I've added some custom request header and status messages that I didn't think were possible with the jquery method.

Comment: In fact I think jQuery's `.html()` will run them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript from an "AJAX" request will not be processed unless you call eval on it - which is not really the best idea

edit this answer is a little too brief - there are ways to native force execution - refer to this more detailed and similar question / answer

[How to Force Javascript to Execute within HTML Response to Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278122/how-to-force-javascript-to-execute-within-html-response-to-ajax-request)

Comment: If he were to use jQuery's `.load()` then that library would take care of evaluating the scripts (with `eval()`).

Comment: @brandtsolovij Found some articles on this about the time you responded. Ended up using a handler that ran after the ajax call fully loaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Scripts which have no `defer` attribute won't be executed when inserted via innerHTML ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).